# Por que el motor de Oracle me devuelve espacios en blanco en un CASE?

Tags: sql, oracle-10g

Estoy realizando el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
       CASE A.TIPO
           WHEN 'ORDENES' THEN 'COBRE-ALTA'
           WHEN 'QUEJAS' THEN 'COBRE-QUEJA'
           ELSE ''
       END
           AS MODULO,
       DECODE (A.TIPO,  'ORDENES', 'COBRE-ALTA',  'QUEJAS', 'COBRE-QUEJA')
           AS MODULO_2 FROM DUAL A;
```

Se supone que la lógica de los campos es la misma pero en el primero me devuelve espacios en blanco al final del campo `"COBRE-ALTA                      "` y el segundo solo `"COBRE-ALTA"` sin espacios al final.
Mi pregunta es el por que se están anexando estos espacios al final.

Comment: Si agrego un TRIM sobre el case lo quita, pero como tal no quiero que tenga que realizar una función adicional el query.

Comment: Eh, probé esto en un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca9d0/10) y no logro replicar el comportamiento que reportas. Qué cliente estás usando para correr esa consulta?

Comment: ¿[Un bug](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=whitespaces-bug)? (Aunque la versión que mencionás en las etiquetas no corresponde a la que se hace referencia en el enlace).

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código cree una tabla llamada `TIPOS` dentro de mi esquema para poder ejecutar tu query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TIPOS (TIPO VARCHAR2(50 BYTE));
```

Agregué registros ejecutando este código:

```sql
INSERT INTO "TIPOS" (TIPO) VALUES ('ORDENES');
INSERT INTO "TIPOS" (TIPO) VALUES ('QUEJAS');
```

El siguiente query me regresa el resultado correcto sin espacios:

```sql
SELECT 
       CASE A.TIPO
           WHEN 'ORDENES' THEN 'COBRE-ALTA'
           WHEN 'QUEJAS' THEN 'COBRE-QUEJA'
           ELSE ''
       END
           AS MODULO,
       DECODE (A.TIPO,  'ORDENES', 'COBRE-ALTA',  'QUEJAS', 'COBRE-QUEJA')
           AS MODULO_2 FROM TIPOS A;
```

No he logrado replicar tu error con el codigo que pusiste en esta pregunta.